# VBA Excel Codename not acquired sometimes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

```
Set tablesheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index))
KodoveJmeno = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(tablesheet.CodeName).Properties("Codename")
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(KodoveJmeno).CodeModule.AddFromString _ "Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)" + Chr(10) _ + "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" + Chr(10) _ + "Call Trideni.Serad(Target, ActiveCell.ListObject.Name)" + Chr(10) _ + "Application.ScreenUpdating = True" + Chr(10) _ + "End Sub"
```

The 2nd command stops with:

> Run-time error '9': subscript out of range

but after F5 it continues without problems - Looks like BUG has been present for many years (Office 2003-2016)!! Any solution for this?

Sometimes it works - after I delete the sheet, open and close VBA with alt+F11 but sometimes it is broken and VERY ANNOYING all the time, destroys productive work.

On some computer everything is OK, on some computers we get errors. Looks like a problem of internal excel procedures sync with VBA communication or something like this (sleep, waiting or alt+f11 in VBA don't not work).

Thx for help

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: to sort on double click

Comment: I would add a hidden worksheet to your workbook that contains the proper code and copy that sheet. Alternatively, use the Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick event in ThisWorkbook.

Comment: The problem is that the desired sheet is recreated even 100 times so the codename changes all the time. And we need to create more sheets automatically not just this one that changes its structure as desired.

Answer (score 0):

As @jkpieterse suggested - use a hidden worksheet.

Create a template sheet and give it a codename of `shtTemplate`.
Add this code to the sheet (NB the Key range selection could probably be better):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
            Range(Selection.CurrentRegion.Offset(, Selection.Column - Selection.CurrentRegion.Resize(, 1).Column).Resize(, 1).Address) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .SetRange Range(Selection.CurrentRegion.Address)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Add a normal code module and add this code:

```
Public Sub CreateSheet()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    shtTemplate.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    shtTemplate.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    shtTemplate.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden 'Hide the template sheet so only VBA can unhide it.

    wrkSht.Name = "Copied Sheet"

End Sub
```

You'll need to add something to give the new sheet the correct unique name.  The sort on double-click will work on each sheet you create.

Comment: Thx, this looks like a solution/workaround of the bug, we will use that. So is this bug really a bug or just a typical Microsoft "feature"?